# Virtualism Inherited in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I picked this code form MSDN resources in C# polymorphism.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override void DoWork() { }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void DoWork()
    {
        // Call DoWork on B to get B's behavior:
        base.DoWork();

        // DoWork behavior specific to C goes here:
        // ...
    }
}
```

It says class C is overriding the DoWork() of B, but the DoWork() method of class B is not made virtual. Since C inherits all methods and data of B, does it also inherit the virtual methods of A (which are available in B, as A is the base class for B)?

What if B does not provide an implementation of DoWork() then would C be accessing the copy of A's virtual method directly to override it?

Also, when C inherits from B does it get a separate copy of A's members or the copy of those of B. 
I guess for separate copy of A's members one has to inherit A separately, like

```
public class C : A, B
```

Correct me if wrong.

EDIT :

```
public class A 
{ 
    public virtual void DoWork() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("In Class A");  
    }
} 
public class B : A 
{ 
    public void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("In Class B"); } 
} 
public class C : B 
{ 
    public void DoWork() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("In Class C"); 
        base.DoWork(); 
    } 
}
```

When I run this on VS C#, virtual keyword is not reqd. in class B's DoWork(), and override keyword in class B's and C's DoWork(), as it generates only a tip-off warning. So does it mean just specifying which base class is being derived in the class name definition as in    public class C : B  is enough to qualify he methods o be virtual in nature?

Also, since C# doesnot provide with the option of multiple inheritance of classes, is there a way to directly use A's implementation of DoWork() from C's class without explicitly creating an object of A and then accessing DoWork() using it?

Answer (score 6):

> It says class C is overriding the DoWork() of B, but the DoWork() method of class B is not made virtual.

When you override a virtual method, it "stays" virtual unless you explicitly seal it with `sealed`. (You can *only* specify the `sealed` modifier for a method if it's also an override method.)

> What if B does not provide an implementation of DoWork() then would C be accessing the copy of A's virtual method directly to override it?

Yes. Or rather, it would invoke A's implementation at execution time. It's not really a "copy".

> Also, when C inherits from B does it get a separate copy of A's members

It's not really clear what you mean here. What sort of "copy" are you talking about, and which members? If you mean which *fields* are in each object, then it's just the union of the fields declared in all the classes up the inheritance chain.

EDIT: In your edited code, you're not overriding anything. You're declaring *new* methods, which aren't called polymorphically. So if you write:

```
A a = new C();
a.DoWork();
```

that will just print "In Class A" - whereas if `B` and `C` *overrode* the virtual method, it would print "In Class C" and then "In Class B".

> Also, since C# doesnot provide with the option of multiple inheritance of classes, is there a way to directly use A's implementation of DoWork() from C's class without explicitly creating an object of A and then accessing DoWork() using it?

Assuming this is in the case where `B` overrides `DoWork`, no. That would break encapsulation - it could break the invariants of `B`, for example.

Comment: @user2450342: I've responded in my edit - but you're now asking a lot of questions within the same post...

Answer (score 1):

`C` is inheriting from `B`, this means it can override all virtual methods in `B`. `Override` means method is still virtual.
If `B` would not give any implementation for `DoWork`, then `base.DoWork` in `C`'s implementation would call the implementation in `A` class - as normally virtual behaves. You should not assume that your base call will be call to exactly `B` method and no other - it's implementation detail that could be changed in future. Important thing is it will call nearet parent implementation of `DoWork`.

And finally - when inheriting B, you also get all the properties, methods and everything inherited from `A`. In `C#` there is nothing like multiple inheritance (meaning `C : A, B` where `C`, `A` and `B` are classes will not work). You cannot get separate copy or anything of `A` with inheritance - you just get what's in `B` (which of course includes things that `B` has inherited from `A` and so on).